# Spectrum of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ the Banach space of continuous real functions in $[0,1]$ equipped with the supremum norm.
We define the operator $A$ for each $x\in X$ by
$$(Ax)(t)=\int_0 ^t x(s)ds, \ \ \ \forall t\in \mathbb{R}.$$
I know that it is a compact operator. How can we find its spectrum $\sigma(A)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every nonzero spectral value of a compact operator is an eigenvalue.

So one method to find the spectrum of $A$ is to determine its eigenvalues. (There aren't many.)

What does an identity

$$\lambda x(t) = \int_0^t x(s)\,ds$$

for all $t\in [0,1]$ imply about $x$?

Comment: Does it imply that $x=0$?

Comment: Indeed it does, @MorganeMaPh. Can you see why it implies that?

Comment: yes by continuity of  $x(s)$. So that means that the spectrum is $\sigma(A)=[0,1]$ and that the Point-spectrum is empty?

Comment: @MorganeMaPh No, we have $\sigma(A) = \{0\}$. The point spectrum is indeed empty, and since $A$ is compact, only $0$ can be a spectral value that is not an eigenvalue. Since the spectrum is nonempty, we have indeed $0 \in \sigma(A) \setminus \sigma_p(A) = \sigma(A)$.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Fischer Nonetheless I don't understand your argument "since A is compact, only 0 can be a spectral value that is not an eigenvalue". I mean an eigenvalue can be in $\sigma(A)$, can't it?

Comment: @MorganeMaPh Eigenvalues are spectral values. The point is that for compact operators, the spectrum consists only of eigenvalues and (possibly) $0$. When the space is infinite-dimensional, then $0$ always belongs to the spectrum of a compact operator, but $0$ may or may not be an eigenvalue. All $\lambda \in \sigma(A)\setminus \{0\}$ are eigenvalues of $A$ if $A$ is compact. $0$ is the only complex number that can belong to the spectrum of a compact operator without being an eigenvalue.

Comment: All right! And here the set of Eigenvalue is empty. I get it. Lot of thanks